# Lua Sleep and Loop function problems

Tags: generics, lua, scripting, lua-table, windows-scripting

So my script currently stops on conditions

```
if profit >= 0.1 then
    stop()
end
```

i want to implement this code into mine so after the target satified it will sleep for 30 secs and then restart my dobet function

if found this

```
function sleep()
t0 = os.clock()
while os.clock() - t0 <= n do
      end
```

but i cant find a way to restart after sleep and restart my dobet() function

my code sample

https://pastebin.com/2Vi2iC81

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
local function sleep(seconds)
    local time = os.time() + seconds
    repeat until os.time() > time
end

chance = 49.5
multiplier = 2
basebet = 0.00000010
bethigh = false
​
function dobet()
    while true do
        if profit >= 0.1 then
            break
        end
    
        if win then
            nextbet = basebet
        else
            nextbet = previousbet * multiplier
        end
        sleep(30)
    end
end
```

this should fix it, let me know if it does not fix it.

Comment: yeah it made my system crash

Answer (score -2):

You can use `goto` to re-execute a code.

Example:

```lua
-- Use local variable instead using global variable, the global method can slowdown your script

local function sleep(s) -- Define a sleep function 
  local ntime = os.time() + s
  repeat until os.time() > ntime
end


-- Setup
local chance = 49.5
local multiplier = 2
local basebet = .00000010
local bethigh = false


-- Main field
local function dobet()
  if profit >= .1 then
    stop()
    
    sleep(30) -- Sleep/Wait for 30 seconds
    goto restart -- Go back to "restart" point
  end

  if win then
    nextbet = basebet

    sleep(30) -- Doing the same thing
    goto restart
  else
    nextbet = previousbet * multiplier

    sleep(30)
    goto restart
  end
end

::restart:: -- Define a "goto" point
dobet()
```

You can also use the `factorial function` method to re-run the function inside the function itself

```lua
local n = 0

local function printHelloWorld()
  if n >= 10 then
    return -- Stop the function basically
  else
    print('Hello World!')

    n = n + 1
    printHelloWorld()
  end
end

printHelloWorld()
```

References:

- Goto feature: http://lua-users.org/wiki/GotoStatement
- Sleep function: http://lua-users.org/wiki/SleepFunction

Comment: im getting a no visible label restart at line 13

Comment: That's weird...  You can use the factorial method above as an alternative to "goto"

Comment: i seen that alot more complicated then restart lol can you explain how this would go with my code

Comment: This is a prime example of when to not use `goto`. You should use a tail call `return dobet()` to restart the "dobet" function - or a while/repeat-until loop - instead.